# Using Button OnClick to input values in to a TEdit

Tags: delphi, events, onclick

I am creating a small app (my first in Delphi 7) which takes several values from the user by `TEdit` and outputs a view calculations. This is all working.

This app is going to be used on a tablet on a fairly small screen, so I don't want to use Windows' on-screen keyboard. I have created a number pad using several buttons for `[0 - 9]`, `[.]` and `[Del]`.

My goal is to use the number pad to input values in to the `TEdit`s.

My question is, how do I maintain focus on a `TEdit` whilst pressing a button that sends a value back to it?

Comment: Why don't you change the KeyboardType property of your TEdit to `NumberPad` so that on-screen keyboard will be shown as NumberPad variant instead of recreating the whole on-screen keyboard by yourself? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.KeyboardType

Answer (score 8):

Use `TSpeedButton` instead of `TButton`. A SpeedButton doesn't take focus while being pressed, so your active Edit will stay focused.